# ios how to make a nsobject file for afnetworking should return response object as a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using AfNetworking lib, i want to write all web-service call in a single file may be in NSobject. how to proceed with it ?

```
-(NSDictionary *)mywebserviceCall
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 manager.requestSerializer= [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer= [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


   @try
 {


 [manager POST:post
 parameters:insert
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject)
 {

 NSLog(@"JSON Response: %@",responseObject);

   NSDictionary *resultDict=responseObject;


 return resultDict;


 }


 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
 NSLog(@"Error code %@",error.description);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ERR",@"ERROR", nil];


 }];

 }
}
```

how can I make this function which will return response or error as dictionary, so that I can call this method from other class

Comment: This function can't return a value as the network operation completes asynchronously. You need to pass a completion block to the method and have the network completion handler invoke that block. Also, don't use @try/@catch in Objective-C

Comment: Thanks, but how to manage that ? can you show by code please